# Order Statistics and Convergence in Probability

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, order-statistics

Let $X_1, ..., X_n$ be iid continuous random variables with cdf $F$ and define $Y_n(x) \equiv \sum_{i=1}^n 1(X_i \leq x)$

Define the inverse cdf as $F^{-1}(y) = \text{inf}\{x \in \mathbb{R} : F(x) \ge y\}$, and $[t] = $ $t$ rounded to the nearest integer.

Finally denote $p \equiv F(x)$.

I wish to show that $X_{[np]} - F^{-1}(Y_n(x)) \xrightarrow{P} 0$

Intuitively this makes perfect sense, since $Y_n$ is an approximation of $p$ and the smallest value for which the cdf exceeds $p$ is the true population quantile, while $X_{[np]}$ approximates this.

Any ideas on how to prove this?

Comment: Your title states "almost sure convergence" but your question says that you wish to show convergence in probability. Which one did you mean?

Comment: Either. I changed the post to probability because I figure it might be easier.  I'm trying to use this as part of a proof about the order statistics' asymptotic distributions.  Changed the title to match now.  Apologies for the confusion

Comment: Please note that $Y_n(x)$ can take values $0,1,2,\ldots$ and $F^{-1}(y)$ is defined for $y\in(0,1)$ only, so in most cases $F^{-1}(Y_n(x))$ is the infimum of empty set.